# Amazon S3 copyObject permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'v got user with all permissions.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using aws-sdk-php-2 to put and copy objects in bucket.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html

Put code works perfect

```
                $client->putObject(array(
                'Bucket'     => 'kiosk',
                'Key'        => 'test/orders/test.csv',
                'SourceFile' => $sourcePath,
            ));
```

After check if object created on S3 via https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3 I'm executing next script.

```
        $result = $client->copyObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'kiosk',
        'CopySource' => 'test/orders/test.csv',
        'Key' => 'test/test.csv',
    ));
```

And I'm getting fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception: AWS Error Code: AllAccessDisabled, Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: XXX, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: All access to this object has been disabled, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.2.1 Guzzle/3.3.1 curl/7.19.7 PHP/5.4.13 thrown in phar:///usr/share/pear/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 89
```

After upload file manually console.aws.amazon.com/s3 I see different error when trying to copy:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\AccessDeniedException: AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: XXX, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: Access Denied, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.2.1 Guzzle/3.3.1 curl/7.19.7 PHP/5.4.13 thrown in phar:///usr/share/pear/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 89
```

I also try to set permissions on file and folder via `console.aws.amazon.com/s3`:
Grantee: Everyone, Open/Download and View Permission and Edit Permission

But still same error.

Comment: I'm having the same error message when trying to access the objects in S3...Did you find the answer?

Comment: For anyone else that has this issue I thought I'd share my resolution - My issue was that I'd uploaded a file with one user account, and tried to copy it with another user which resulted in the access denied error.

Answer (score 93):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same issue recently while doing work on a legacy project.

```php
$this->client->copyObject([
    'Bucket'        => $this->bucket,
    'CopySource'    => $file,
    'Key'           => str_replace($source, $destination, $file),
]);
```

All of the my other S3 calls worked except for `copyObject` continued to throw an **ACCESS DENIED** error. After some digging, I finally figured out [why](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_copyObject).

[image: AWS v2 SDK CopySource Documentation]

I was passing just the key and making the assumption that the bucket being passed was what both the source and destination would use. Turns out that is an incorrect assumption. The source **must** have the bucket name prefixed.

Here was my solution:

```php
$this->client->copyObject([
    'Bucket'        => $this->bucket,
    // Added the bucket name to the copy source
    'CopySource'    => $this->bucket.'/'.$file,
    'Key'           => str_replace($source, $destination, $file),
]);
```

It says "Access Denied" because it thinks the first part of your key/folder is actually the name of the bucket which either doesn't exist or you really don't have access to.

Comment: Same thing happens when you use the aws cli `aws s3api copy-object` command. You must provide the bucket name again as part of the `--key` argument even though you specified it for the `--bucket` argument and you are copying within the same bucket.

Comment: thank, it's work for me. But cannot get result response

Comment: Avoid a leading forward slash on the key

Comment: You're an absolute life saver. I'd only been debugging this for around an hour, but I could've spent SO much longer on it. Thank you. FYI you don't need the bucket name in the new 'Key' you're creating, just the 'CopySource'.

Comment: Nice. Didn't pay attention that in docs they put this hint `CopySource: "/sourcebucket/HappyFacejpg", `.

Answer (score 25):

Found out what the issue is here; being an AWS newbie I struggled here for a bit until I realized that each policy for the users you set needs to clearly allow the service you're using.

In this case I hadn't set the user to be allowed into S3.

Goto IAM then goto Users and click on the particular user that has the credentials you're using. From there goto Permissions tab, then click on Attach User Policy and find the S3 policy under select policy template.  This should fix your problem.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did and still get AWS Error Code:   AccessDenied
Error Type:       Client any pointers please

Answer (score 6):

Popular answer was on point, but still had issues. Had to include ACL option.

```
$this->client->copyObject([
  'Bucket'        => $this->bucket,
  // Added the bucket name to the copy source
  'CopySource'    => $this->bucket.'/'.$file,
  'Key'           => str_replace($source, $destination, $file),
  'ACL'           => 'public-read'
]);
```

ACL can be one of these value 'ACL' => 'private|public-read|public-read-write|authenticated-read|aws-exec-read|bucket-owner-read|bucket-owner-full-control',