# How to resolve 403 aws error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm getting a 403 error when I try to upload a file (with carrierwave / fog) on my rails site. Everything is working locally, and on a different site I built that uses the same aws bucket.

Not sure how to troubleshoot this... Here is my full log:

```
2016-04-16T23:46:14.648046+00:00 app[web.1]:    (3.8ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-04-16T23:46:14.648461+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 250ms
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650859+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650868+00:00 app[web.1]: Excon::Errors::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650869+00:00 app[web.1]: excon.error.response
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650873+00:00 app[web.1]:   :cookies       => [
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650874+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Connection"       => "close"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650872+00:00 app[web.1]:   :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code><Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message><RequestId>E72C3A0BE72715F6</RequestId><HostId>sLnw1x3KEV4ugpi3pHCh2DwoP0eIl/mX18D3789QDSWriYM7vg6DFFUfug9ylyuGExvhaIlXUIo=</HostId></Error>"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650873+00:00 app[web.1]:   ]
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650874+00:00 app[web.1]:   :headers       => {
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650876+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Date"             => "Sat, 16 Apr 2016 23:46:13 GMT"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650875+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650878+00:00 app[web.1]:     "x-amz-id-2"       => "sLnw1x3KEV4ugpi3pHCh2DwoP0eIl/mX18D3789QDSWriYM7vg6DFFUfug9ylyuGExvhaIlXUIo="
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650878+00:00 app[web.1]:     "x-amz-request-id" => "E72C3A0BE72715F6"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650877+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650879+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650880+00:00 app[web.1]:   :local_address => "172.17.72.90"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650880+00:00 app[web.1]:   :host          => "s3.amazonaws.com"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650881+00:00 app[web.1]:   :local_port    => 56731
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650882+00:00 app[web.1]:   :path          => "/uploads/song/track/5/snare_card_2.wav"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650882+00:00 app[web.1]:   :port          => 443
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650883+00:00 app[web.1]:   :remote_ip     => "54.231.14.104"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650883+00:00 app[web.1]:   :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650884+00:00 app[web.1]:   :status        => 403
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650885+00:00 app[web.1]:   :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
2016-04-16T23:46:14.650885+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might help,

[Amazon S3 copyObject permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900245/amazon-s3-copyobject-permission)

Check if the access policy has been defined properly

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how this disaster error message came to be. When I set my heroku config for the s3 bucket I called it S3_BUCKET_KEY, which didn't match the variable in my aws initializer "S3_BUCKET", so nothing worked.

Steps I took to resolve the issue:

On the command-line -

```
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET="bucket_name"
```